# Update progress bar when database insertion going on in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi I need to update my progress bar progress when data base insertion in sqlite is going on because it takes 5 min.

But when data base insertion goes on ui get hang and i can not do any more operation.i use
this method to update progress bar

```
-(void)setProgress:(float)progress
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        [progressview setProgress:progress animated:YES];
    });
}
```

So please suggest me some way to update progress bar when database insertion going on

Answer (score 0):

The UI is hanging because probably you are doing the database insertion in main thread.

So change the database insertion method call like:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        //call the database insertion method here
    });
```

If you are updating the progress bar from that method, then call it like:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [progressview setProgress:progress animated:YES];
});
```

Never update UI elements from other threads, update it from main thread only.

Answer (score 0):

Please read my writeup on using background managed object contexts: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

You could send a notification about the progress from sich a background queue and then dispatch_async on the main thread the update of the progress bar.